# How can you know you are performing a legal operation?

Tags: proof-writing, fake-proofs

There are many examples in math where you have fake proofs of something because you do something extraneous that you were not allowed to do. For example:

Let $$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \dots = \log 2,$$ but $$1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \dots = \frac{3}{2}\log 2$$ (rearranging the series). In elementary calculus, we are taught that we cannot rearrange series precisely for this reason: We may change the value that the series equals. Another example would be the equation

$$\large{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}} = 2.$$ Then we use the property that it repeats to see that $x^2 = 2,$ which implies that $x = \sqrt{2}$ for positive $x$. But then, if we wish to solve $$\large{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}} = 4,$$ then using the same trick we see that $$x^4 = 4 \implies \sqrt[4]{x^4} = \sqrt[4]{4} \implies x = \sqrt{2}.$$ Once again, we did something we are not allowed to do.

My question is therefore: how do we know that we aren't doing something illegal when exploring mathematics? When we try to solve problems, or discover patterns or learn, how can we tell when we do something extraneous?

Comment: "How do we know that we aren't doing something illegal when exploring mathematics? " By following the axioms and proving it from the axioms - and not by assuming something could be valid, like $x^2=2$ would imply $x=2$, without proof.

Comment: I don't think there's a right answer to this. Intuition develops with practice

Comment: Binary operations are defined on two elements and can be extended to finitely many by induction, but new definitions are needed to apply them infinitely many times

Comment: Well, arriving at falsities or contradictions is a good hint that something wrong!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner In that case, how do we know that a new definition satisfies our current axioms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By knowing very well the rules of the game i.e. 1) the definitions, 2) the axioms, and 3) the theorems within a given math theory. A tiny change, or addition, or even misinterpretation of any of these... and a slip may happen leading to various paradoxes, false proofs, etc.

Math is not about syntactic, mechanical manipulation of mysterious symbols; there's deep meaning behind every symbol. Make sure you know the meaning of the symbol, only then use it.

E.g. when I see this

$\large{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}$

it is not immediately clear to me what it means.

So I would exercise extra care if I have to manipulate this expression.

Comment: But taking the field axioms here, it's unclear what we would violate.

Comment: @politeproofs No, that is not so unclear. Popular mistakes show what always happens. You want an example? That $\Bbb Z/4$ is a field, forgetting that there would be zero divisors, and that a field has no zero divisors. I would say, we know the top $10$ "mistakes" for fields (just looking at the exams). Or, if you prefer analysis - typical mistake I saw, is cancelling without thinking. So $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=sin$.

Comment: @politeproofs See J. W. Tanner's note below your question. When you start playing with infinite things, first ask yourself "wait... where did we define this thing and how exactly did we define it?!" Math is not about syntactic, mechanical manipulation of mysterious symbols, there's deep meaning behind every symbol.

Comment: That is a good point I suppose, but I find that for some problems, you may not know if you are doing something well-defined in infinite quantities. For example, you are not going to find (or at least I haven't) a definition which states what $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}$ means

Comment: @polite proofs Would you please point out the axiom telling you that something like $\large{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}$ *exists*, or makes sense?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I can't, that is pretty much my question (what to do in such a situation—not knowing). However, with the use of a computer you can see that it does indeed converge.

Comment: @politeproofs Exactly... If you don't find definition for it, you are not allowed to manipulate it. In fact different authors sometimes give different meanings to same looking expressions. So... make sure you are clear for yourself what meaning you put into this expression. Only then start playing with it.

Comment: @peter.petrov But in that case, how is progress made? As I said, using a computer we can find that it converges.

Comment: That's fine... That means this expression to you represents a limit of some sort. But noone says you can mechanically manipulate it as other finite versions of that expression (e.g. $a^5$).

Comment: @peter.petrov I completely agree with that. But this means that you are stuck. How do you proceed with "care"?

Comment: @politeproofs *What* converges? Your expression with the dots? Or a well-defined recursion you didn't tell us? And for what values of $x$ does it converge, for all real $x$?

Comment: @ProfessorVector $x = \sqrt{2}$ will converge, as an example. As for the other details, we wouldn't know what $x$ it converges for if we are trying to find out information about that expression.

Comment: I'm typing more slowly, so you can follow: *what* converges? "Convergence" is a property of an infinite sequence. As long as you didn't define that sequence, you're *not* talking sense.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I think my example is quite simple. If we found the expression $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}$, and we wanted to find for which values of $x$ it does equal a real number, then how can we proceed without performing an extraneous operation? And this particular example isn't of relevance either, my question was more general while highlighting this example.

Comment: @ProfessorVector https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#In_mathematical_notation

Comment: @polite proofs Then, you should ask you question at Wikipedia. Mathematics Stack Exchange is a mathematical site. I've just voted to close your question, as you refuse to give a mathematical definition.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I've given a definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990529/how-can-you-know-you-are-performing-a-legal-operation/3990533?noredirect=1#comment8235265_3990533). Just because you seem to dislike it is not my fault.

Answer (score 2):

These problems always surface when you try to work with infinite expressions. As was already pointed out in comments, infinite expressions like $x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}$ are not part of standard mathematical notation, so when dealing with them one needs to define what they mean. In this case, you probably mean something like
$$ x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}} := \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \qquad \text{where} \qquad
a_0 = x \quad\text{and}\quad a_{n + 1} = x^{a_n} \quad\text{for $n \geq 1$}. $$
But it is possible to imagine other definitions, like taking a different $a_0$, setting $a_{n+1} = x^{x^{a_n}}$, or any number of other modifications. Are these equivalent? Maybe. If so, this needs to be proven using theorems about limits. If not, we need to carefully distinguish them.

A famous example is the equation
$$ 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n = -\frac{1}{12}. $$
Clearly this does not make sense with the usual definition of the infinite sum
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n = \lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^t n, $$
which would give $\infty$. But mathematicians have other, less standard, ways of defining what infinite sums are, which they find useful, which share properties of the finite sum that they consider imporant, and which indeed make the sum equal to $-1/12$.

So as long as you know exactly what every piece of notation means, you should know exactly what you may and may not do with each mathematical object. If you don't, you are not reasoning formally, but are in the process of exploring or inventing new mathematics (which is a valid and important activity for mathematicians).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate it and upvoted.